# Account missing from WHM

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm

I cannot locate a account from WHM (list accounts). I can access cpanel for that domain (mysite.com/cpanel).It just disappeared from whm. So now I cant directly go to mysite.com. I don't have a backup but all the files and db exist for that domain. Any solution to this problem because I cant find such a thing.

How do i find the option via WHM Control Panel?

Comment: Was is added as main domain or it was added as an addon domain?

Comment: Any response you was valid? You solucionaste the problem? This well come over here, continue discussions, and provide more than just questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root SSH access of our server then check **/etc/trueuserdomains** and **/etc/userdomains** file because you without root access you can not check these files. if you have only cPanel access then you need to contact your hosting provider to check your mission domain logs.

Answer (score 0):

Was there any cPanel upgrade performed on server recently?

If you have root access then login to your server via SSH and run the following command:

$ /scripts/rebuildcpusers

It should rebuild files for each domain under /var/cpanel/users from source databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you has a root acces to server

1. Access SSH to server
2. Check /etc/userdomains – this file should contain the the domain and username that’s missing.
3. Check /etc/trueuserdomains `domain.com: username`
4. Check /var/cpanel/users/USERNAME

/var/cpanel/users/USERNAME

```
DNS=domain.com
IP=ipaddress
USER=username
OWNER=root (This will be set to ‘root’ unless the account was created under a reseller).
```

5. Check the Apache configuration file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and make sure that a virtual host exists for your domain. Try to rebuild apache `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`
6. Finally run `/scripts/updateuserdomains`